# Getting time out error while installing application

Tags: android

Hello everyone I have prepared my project using target `android 4.0.3`( api level 15). But in case of running the project sum times I get time out error I have also increased the time form DDMS  to 60000 ms but still getting error

```
myProject.apk not installed :'timeout'
```

Comment: you are not the only one this happens to! It happens in my projects as well from time to time, but usually reconnecting the USB or restarting adb.exe helps.

Comment: but it is very frustating to restart the adb again and again. why this happens only in upper target. i never get this problem in target 2.3.3